# Some tests crashes when I'm running them all

Tags: java, intellij-idea, appium

Hy guys, I'm creating automation test using java, appium & intellij idea.
When I run all class test ( By click right mouse button on the the class that contain test and choosing Run all), Some tests are crashes with Error: Error: socket hang up
But when I run the only crashed test, it's passed.

I tried to set more time to wait , but still not working.

Anyone come across this and can help?

```
@BeforeEach
    public void openAddPolicyCoverageScreen() throws IOException {
        try {
            drawerNavigation.getSideMenuButton().click();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(drawerNavigation.getDisconnectButton())).isDisplayed();
            drawerNavigation.getAddTempPolicy().click();
            Assertions.assertTrue(policyForAnotherDriver.getPageTitle().isDisplayed());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            captureScreenshot("openAddTempPolicyScreen ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Test
    @Description("Verify that the page contains all period options")
    @Order(1)
    public void allPeriodsExist() throws IOException {
        try {
            for (MobileElement element : policyForAnotherDriver.periodsComponents()) {
                Assertions.assertTrue(element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            captureScreenshot("allPeriodsExist", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Test
    @Description("Check date on periods buttons")
    @Order(2)
    public void dateExist() throws IOException {
        try {
            for (MobileElement element : policyForAnotherDriver.periodsComponents()) {
                System.out.println(element.isDisplayed());
                System.out.println(policyForAnotherDriver.getPeriodDaysText(element));
                System.out.println(element.findElement(By.className("android.widget.TextView")).getText());
                System.out.println(element.findElement(By.className("android.widget.TextView")).getText());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            captureScreenshot("allPeriodsExist", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Error from logcat:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Michaels-MBP', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1824:7ef0:bcb9:27c9%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {app: /Users/mykll/Desktop/harel_..., appPackage: com.harel.harel_switch, autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: UiAutomator2, browserName: , databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app: /Users/mykll/Desktop/harel_..., autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: UiAutomator2, browserName: , deviceName: 2623e8172c057ece, fullReset: false, noReset: true, platformName: android, platformVersion: 9}, deviceApiLevel: 28, deviceManufacturer: samsung, deviceModel: SM-G973F, deviceName: RF8MA2EH90D, deviceScreenDensity: 420, deviceScreenSize: 1080x2280, deviceUDID: RF8MA2EH90D, fullReset: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, noReset: true, pixelRatio: 2.625, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 9, statBarHeight: 112, takesScreenshot: true, viewportRect: {height: 1930, left: 0, top: 112, width: 1080}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 7cf3f18b-0cd3-42ce-a2d4-56f75af72557

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:45)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:295)
    at AppiumBase.BaseTestClass.captureScreenshot(BaseTestClass.java:43)
    at Tests.NewDriver.openAddPolicyCoverageScreen(NewDriver.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassTestDescriptor.java:436)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$14(ClassTestDescriptor.java:424)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:136)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Can you post your testcode? I am suspecting you are closing certain functions at the end of every test that should only be executed once instead of in every testmethod.

Comment: @Quadrivics Sorry=] Added